# Mi codigo no reconoce variables hechas con comando "exec()"

Tags: python, pyqt5, exec

Estoy tratando de optimizar un codigo de pyqt, es el siguiente:

```
        nombres_iconos = ["emerald", "check proceso", "flecha copiar", "vacio limpiar", "flecha pegar", "vacio cortar"]

        for ind, nom in enumerate(nombres_iconos):
            print(ind, dir())
            exec("icon" + str(ind) + " = QtGui.QIcon()")
            print(exec("icon" + str(ind)))
            exec('icon' + str(ind) + '.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\' + nom + '.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)')

        print(dir())
##        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
##        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\emerald.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
##
##        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
##        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\check proceso.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
##
##        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
##        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\flecha copiar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
##
##        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
##        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\vacio limpiar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
##
##        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
##        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\flecha pegar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
##
##        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
##        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(camino(LIBRERIA) + "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\vacio cortar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

        Envoltorio.setWindowIcon(icon0)
```

Esta es la parte inicial del codigo, lo que esta comentado funciona, sin embargo quiero optimizarlo con el ciclo for y usando la funcion exec para asignar las variables "icon*n*", tambien coloque un print() para imprimir el directorio y efectivamente imprime correctamente el nombre de las variables, una vez fuera del ciclo for vuelvo a imprimir el dir(), pero cuando llega el "Envoltorio.setWindowIcon(icon0)" no reconoce el la variable, a continuacion esta el error:

```
0 ['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
None
1 ['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'icon0', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
None
2 ['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'icon0', 'icon1', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
None
3 ['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'icon0', 'icon1', 'icon2', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
None
4 ['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'icon0', 'icon1', 'icon2', 'icon3', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
None
5 ['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'icon0', 'icon1', 'icon2', 'icon3', 'icon4', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
None
['Envoltorio', 'brush', 'icon0', 'icon1', 'icon2', 'icon3', 'icon4', 'icon5', 'ind', 'nom', 'nombres_iconos', 'palette', 'self']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    v_mcd_mcm2()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\eme\i\iva03o.py", line 419, in v_mcd_mcm2
    dialogo = Articulacion()     # Se crea un dialogo que sera la bandeja del los elementos
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\eme\i\iva03o.py", line 400, in __init__
    self.envoltorio.elementos(self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\eme\i\iva03o.py", line 79, in elementos
    Envoltorio.setWindowIcon(icon0)
NameError: name 'icon0' is not defined
```

No entiendo porque si es las variables estan en el espacio de nombres no las reconoce

Comment: Hola BBriam, ¿por qué te complicas creando variables en tiempo de ejecución con la perdida de legibilidad y los problemas de depuración que ya ves en vez de usar un contenedor como una lista o un diccionario con objetos QtGui.QIcon?

Comment: Se me olvidaba, ¿ese fragmento de código está en una función/metodo/clase o en el espacio de nombres global?

Comment: Estan en una clase, no en el shell, de hecho en el shell funciona, pero no en la clase y bueno efectivamente lo hago para ganar legibilidad, porque es una ventana simple y tiene mucha redundancia y construcciones que se repiten, y fijate que pasaria de 12 lineas a 7 solo en este caso, hay mas parte del codigo que se repite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a ver que dice la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#exec):

> modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.

---

> no se deben intentar modificaciones en el diccionario `locals` predeterminado. Pase un diccionario local explícito si necesita ver los efectos del código en `locals` después de que la función `exec()` retorne.

Efectivamente, en Python 3 (dónde `exec` es una función) no se permite que se modifique el "diccionario" `locals` directamente. Ésto es básicamente una decisión de optimización.

El espacio de nombres local de una función/método se almacenan realmente internamente usando un array, no un diccionario como `globals`. Dciho array y sus índices se definen durante la generación del bytecode (tiempo de "compilación"), no en tiempo de ejecución. Ésto permite una serie de optimizaciones que de otra forma son imposibles.

Dicho de otro modo, el intérprete tiene que conocer el nombre de toda variable local en tiempo de definición, el enlazado con el objeto asociado no le importa en absoluto, eso se hace en tiempo de ejecución (late binding), pero a la hora de generar el bytecode debe conocer todas las variables locales que existirán.

```
def foo():
    exec("var = 13")
    print(var)
```

> ```
> >>> foo()
> Excepción "unhandled NameError"
>  name 'var' is not defined
> ```

lo que dice la documentación es que debemos hacer ésto.

```
def foo():
    locals_dict = {}
    exec("var = 13", globals(), locals_dict)
    var = locals_dict['var']
    print(var)
```

> ```
> >>> foo()
> 13
> ```

Si no damos cuenta, no se han creado ninguna variable local en tiempo de ejecución, tanto `locals_dict` como `var` son conocidas por el parser en tiempo de definición.

Pasa exactamente igual si intentamos asignar con [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

---

> El contenido de este diccionario no debe modificarse; los cambios pueden no afectar los valores de las variables locales y libres utilizadas por el intérprete.

Efectivamente, cualquier intento de definición o resignación es ignorado:

```
def foo():
    var1 = 0
    var2 = []
    locals()["var1"] += 3 # Reasignación, ignorada
    locals()["var2"] += [5] # Solo referenciar, objeto mutable
    locals()["var5"] = 8
    print(var1)
    print(var2)
    #print(var5) # ERROR
```

> ```
> >>> foo()
> 0
> [5]
> ```

Si estamos en un método de instancia, lo que si nos permite hacer `exec` es generar atributos de instancia en tiempo de ejecución, dado que ésto no modifica el espacio de nombres local de la función:

```
class Foo:

    def bar(self):
        exec("self.var = 13")

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar()
>>> foo.var
13
```

Aunque, dado éste caso, mejor usar `setattr`...

`exec` y su prima hermana `eval` son dos herramients muy potentes (y peligrosas mal empleadas) que tienen algunos casos de utilidad, pero por norma general, crear variables en tiempo de ejecución es una práctica mala, ya sea con `exec` o con cualquier otro método como modificar  `globals()`  o usar `setattr`.

En muy pocos casos es ésto necesario y está justificado, en el resto es simplemente una mala idea. El código se vuelve mucho más ilegible (menos código no significa mayor legibilidad), mucho más difícil de mantener en el futuro y de depurar, los linters y analizadores de código se van a quejar, con razón además, etc.

En vez de recurrir a éstas prácticas, es mucho más eficiente y legible, además de facilitar el mantenimiento y depuración, usar un contenedor, una lista sirve, pero un diccionario suele ser mejor opción:

```
import os


nombres_iconos = [
    "emerald", "check proceso", "flecha copiar",
    "vacio limpiar", "flecha pegar", "vacio cortar"
     ]

icons = {}
for ind, nom in enumerate(nombres_iconos):
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(
        QtGui.QPixmap(
            os.path.join(camino(LIBRERIA), "\\__pycache__\\salidas\\iconos\\", f"{nom}.png"
            ),
        QtGui.QIcon.Normal,
        QtGui.QIcon.Off
        )
    icons[f"icon{ind}"] = icon

Envoltorio.setWindowIcon(icons["icon0"])
```

---

### Nota "histórica"

En Python 2, `exec` era un estamento, no una función, en éste caso si que se permitía la modificación del espacio local, a costa de no poder optimizar esa función... Cuando el ínterprete se encontraba con el estamento al generar el bytecode, establecía esa función como "no optimizable".

En Python 3, aparte del problema de la optimización (y teneindo en cuenta que los casos reales en los que `exec` es necesario), es una fucnión preconstruida, por lo que es programador puede hacer: exec = "Hola mundo"...y ya `exec` es otra cosa...

Comment: Gracias por la informacion de la causa y la alternativa, habia usado eval antes para retornar copias de algun objeto en particular, y exec no la habia usado, y gracias por la explicacion porque leyendo esas dos frases de documentacion no habria entendido, por cierto siempre habia tenido en mente que mientras menos lineas mas legible, por eso ni siquiera habia pensado en una alternativa, gracias por la aclaratoria